# iOS Handling the UIBarButtonItem the way of Unwinding Segue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, storyboard

In iOS 6 you have Unwinding Segue to return to previous view controller.

I am now working with storyboard, to figure that thing. And i am on iOS 5 where i dont have Unwinding Segue.

The picture explains the situation:
[image]

In third window (i think its officially called story) there is a Done button.

How to make that button return an object with text on screen and return to window 2?
There, i window 2 the table should refries, but that is out of the scope of this question.

What i did was to implement IBOutlet in ThirdWindowViewController (lets call it that), which is linked to IBAction method.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextView* textView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) Note* note;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem* doneButton;

- (void) configureView;
- (IBAction) doneAction:(id)sender;
- (BOOL) prepareNoteForTransition;
```

EDIT_01

As Tom wrote, you need a delegate. That is the way i actually did it, with methods i put above. I just thought that there is some more apple-specific way to do it, like that Segues. or some alternatives.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set a delegate property in the 'story' view controller for the presenting view controller:

NotesViewController.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showStoryViewController"]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];
    }
}

- (void)storyViewControllerDidPressDoneWithText:(NSString *)text note:(Note *)note
{
    self.note = [NSString stringWithString:note];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Story.m

```
- (IBAction)doneAction:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate storyViewControllerDidPressDoneWithNote:self.textView.text note:self.note];
}
```

also make sure to `#import "NotesViewController.h"` in `Story.h`

Answer (score 2):

I also not sure that understood your question, but if you want an action for Done button to go back just write `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand it well, but you can draw a segue from your `Done` button to the second view controller and implement `prepareForSegue:`. This way you can send any information from your last view controller to the destination one.